# Do I need to collect my luggage between connecting flights at LHR?

Tags: luggage, lhr, british-airways

I got  connecting flights with lay over time of 20 hrs, will my luggage get shifted else should i carry the luggage between connecting flights ?

Comment: Could you rephrase more clearly? Are both flights with the same airline on the same ticket? Assume this is LHR - are both from the same terminal? Please edit your question to explain exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yes both flights on the same airline ticket, and yes both of them on same terminal, and my question is that whether i should carry luggage between this flights or will they take care of and so that i would collect at my destination ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both flights are on the same ticket, with the same airline, then you don't need to worry about it.  The airline will check your bags through to your final destination, and you won't need to carry them yourself.

You can confirm this at check-in when you start your trip, but all should be fine.